How to add visitors count to a website built using mkdocs?
I recently started using Obsidian and am pushing it to Github and using github actions to build website at 'https://pratyaydhond.github.io/obsidianSync/'.
I want to enable visitors count, either on the website or just as a parameter I can use to analyze. How do I add that to the website?
I tried reading various mkdocs but many suggest adding counter to github user profile md file and not to mcdocs generated static website.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
